# Law of Demeter in `includes` and `group` queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I apply law of demeter on this code?

I know how to do it by creating separate methods, scope.... but I'm not sure how to do it with queries like this.

```
  pages = Seo::Page.active
    .path_with(category)
    .includes(seo_area: :suburb)
    .group('suburbs.state')
```

`scope :path_with, -> category { where('path like ?', "/#{category}/%") }`

Answer (score 0):

you can create class-methods or new scopes to encapsulate the logic in the `Seo::Page` class.

```
def self.grouped(category)
  active
    .path_with(category)
    .includes(seo_area: :suburb)
    .group('suburbs.state')
end

pages = Seo::Page.grouped(category)
```